# Regular expression to replace number range in column with individual numbers

Tags: r, replace

I am looking for a regular expression to convert text indicating a range of numbers in a given cell of a specific column to the individual numbers in question.

For example

```
Seeds<-c("Seeds.jpg 1-7-Sunflower[seeds 1-7.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 8-Sunflower[seeds 8.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 9-15-Sunflower[seeds 9-15.jpg]")

Pot<-c("1.jpg-Sunflower[1.jpg]", "2.jpg-Sunflower[2.jpg]", "3.jpg-Sunflower[3.jpg]", "4.jpg-Sunflower[4.jpg]", "5.jpg-Sunflower[5.jpg]", "6.jpg-Sunflower[6.jpg]", "7.jpg-Sunflower[7.jpg]", "8.jpg-Sunflower[8.jpg]", "9.jpg-Sunflower[9.jpg]", "10.jpg-Sunflower[10.jpg]", "11.jpg-Sunflower[11.jpg]", "12.jpg-Sunflower[12.jpg]", "13.jpg-Sunflower[13.jpg]", "14.jpg-Sunflower[14.jpg]", "15.jpg-Sunflower[15.jpg]")

Garden<-data.frame(Pot,Seeds)
```

I wish to create a new column, `Seeds2`, that looks something like this:

```
Seeds2<-c("Seeds.jpg 1-Sunflower[seed 1.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 2-Sunflower[seeds 2.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 3-Sunflower[seed 3.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 4-Sunflower[seeds 4.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 5-Sunflower[seed 5.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 6-Sunflower[seeds 6.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 7-Sunflower[seed 7.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 8-Sunflower[seeds 8.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 9-Sunflower[seed 9.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 10-Sunflower[seeds 10.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 11-Sunflower[seed 11.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 12-Sunflower[seeds 12.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 13-Sunflower[seed 13.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 14-Sunflower[seeds 14.jpg]","Seeds.jpg 15-Sunflower[seeds 15.jpg]")
```

or

```
Seeds2<-c(("Seeds.jpg 1,2,3,4,5,6,7-Sunflower[seeds 1,2,3,4,5,6,7.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 8-Sunflower[seeds 8.jpg]", "Seeds.jpg 9-15-Sunflower[seeds 9-15.jpg]")
```

`seq.int()` is seemingly close to what I want, but cannot create new cells in a column based on this input, or read text, to my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `gsub` within `sapply`:

```
Garden$Seeds2 <- sapply(seq_len(nrow(Garden)), function(x)
  gsub("\\d+-\\d+|\\d+", x, Garden$Seeds[x]))
```

Output (of `Garden$Seeds2` only for clarity):

```
# [1,] "Seeds.jpg 1-Sunflower[seeds 1.jpg]"  
# [2,] "Seeds.jpg 2-Sunflower[seeds 2.jpg]"  
# [3,] "Seeds.jpg 3-Sunflower[seeds 3.jpg]"  
# [4,] "Seeds.jpg 4-Sunflower[seeds 4.jpg]"  
# [5,] "Seeds.jpg 5-Sunflower[seeds 5.jpg]"  
# [6,] "Seeds.jpg 6-Sunflower[seeds 6.jpg]"  
# [7,] "Seeds.jpg 7-Sunflower[seeds 7.jpg]"  
# [8,] "Seeds.jpg 8-Sunflower[seeds 8.jpg]"  
# [9,] "Seeds.jpg 9-Sunflower[seeds 9.jpg]"  
#[10,] "Seeds.jpg 10-Sunflower[seeds 10.jpg]"
#[11,] "Seeds.jpg 11-Sunflower[seeds 11.jpg]"
#[12,] "Seeds.jpg 12-Sunflower[seeds 12.jpg]"
#[13,] "Seeds.jpg 13-Sunflower[seeds 13.jpg]"
#[14,] "Seeds.jpg 14-Sunflower[seeds 14.jpg]"
#[15,] "Seeds.jpg 15-Sunflower[seeds 15.jpg]"
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this so that the adjacent columns in the row are also preserved?

Comment: @Zard22 Thats what this should do - it creates a new column in `Garden` and doesn't replace any of the existing ones. I just put the output of the one column because it was hard to reason on the screen. Let me know if you need more help or if I misinterpreted your question!

Comment: This does not seem to work quite properly. I am in actuality working with a different, but conceptually similar, dataset, and it creates values that are not in the number range and skips certain values. I think my initial example may not have been the best and I apologize for that. 

What I want to do is preserve other rows, but have the corresponding, extended number in the column Seeds to Pot. For example, if Pot has a value "3.jpg-Sunflower[3.jpg]", I want the corresponding unraveled "3.jpg-Sunflower[3.jpg]" from the "1-7" in the Seeds column. They must be in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution where using `str_extract_all` from the `stringr` package:

```
ub <- max(as.numeric(unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(Seeds, "\\d+"))))
sprintf("Seeds.jpg %1$i-Sunflower[seed %1$i.jpg]", 1:ub)

 [1] "Seeds.jpg 1-Sunflower[seed 1.jpg]"   "Seeds.jpg 2-Sunflower[seed 2.jpg]"  
 [3] "Seeds.jpg 3-Sunflower[seed 3.jpg]"   "Seeds.jpg 4-Sunflower[seed 4.jpg]"  
 [5] "Seeds.jpg 5-Sunflower[seed 5.jpg]"   "Seeds.jpg 6-Sunflower[seed 6.jpg]"  
 [7] "Seeds.jpg 7-Sunflower[seed 7.jpg]"   "Seeds.jpg 8-Sunflower[seed 8.jpg]"  
 [9] "Seeds.jpg 9-Sunflower[seed 9.jpg]"   "Seeds.jpg 10-Sunflower[seed 10.jpg]"
[11] "Seeds.jpg 11-Sunflower[seed 11.jpg]" "Seeds.jpg 12-Sunflower[seed 12.jpg]"
[13] "Seeds.jpg 13-Sunflower[seed 13.jpg]" "Seeds.jpg 14-Sunflower[seed 14.jpg]"
[15] "Seeds.jpg 15-Sunflower[seed 15.jpg]"
```

This works by extracting the largest value in the string, in this case 15. Then creating your character vector using sequential numbers from `1:15`. If you have something like 1-13, 15 then this will make 14, FYI.

Comment: This is close to what I want--for clarity (which I did not initially provide), I would like to preserve row information. E.g., I would like to separate into individual seeds from a range denoted in text, but also preserve adjacent columns. That is, I do not want only this data in a data frame, but the corresponding data in the row, in adjacent columns. 

`Values1<-c(10, 23, 34, 55, 66, 79, 52, 8, 81, 70, 200, 50, 65, 29, 105)
Values2<-c(105, 29, 65, 50, 200, 70, 81, 8, 52, 79, 66, 55, 34, 23, 10)
Garden(Pot, Seeds, Values1, Values2)`

This would be a more accurate reflection. Sorry.

Comment: @Zard22 it is not clear to me what you are trying to do. In the first row how do you get 10 in `Values1`? How do you get 105 in `Values2`?

Comment: My posted solution was intended to be assigned as a new column, therefore preserving your other information: `Garden$Seeds2 <- sprintf(...)`